# Object: "DF" not found when knitting rmd

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown, knitr

I get this error when knitting any rmd. file using this data set (Aviste_Affect_Data).(The problem also happens with other data frames when I tried to reproduce the problem) All of the code within the files run and the data set itself appears to be fine (it was imported from SPSS). The error occurs on the first line of code in each rmd. file and if I delete that line the error just happens again on the next line of code and so on.
This is the first line of code that the error occurs on, which again runs fine (the package dplyr is being used):

```
Data_na2014<-Aviste_Affect_Data %>% filter(!Year==14)
```

Error Message:

> Error in eval(las, parent, parent) : object 'Aviste_Affect_Data' not found Calls:  ...withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> $>$ ->eval ->eval Execution halted

If I try different code as the first code, the error is mostly the same:

```
Aviste_Affect_Data$Worry<-as.numeric(Aviste_Affect_Data$x78)
```

Error Message:

> Error in eval(expo,envir,enclos) : object 'Aviste_Affect_Data' not found Calls:  ...handle-> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval Execution halted

Comment: "The error occurs on the first line of code in each rmd. file" So, you are not importing the data?

Comment: Rendering of r-markdown docs are typically done in a different environment than your globalenv, which means that variables you see on your console are not necessarily what is visible to the code. I suggest you look into [parameterized reports](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/parameterized-reports.html).